# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I primarily come from a ASP.NET WebForms background. I am working on an application with a complicated layout scheme. Because of this, i was hoping to have all of my layout code in, well, _Layout.cshtml. My challenge is, there is custom javascript logic associated with each page. I've found that if this JavaScript is included in the middle of my page, it doesn't work. So what I wanted to do was move it elsewhere. But in order to do this, I need something similar to the ASP.NET WebForms PlaceHolder control. Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="myLayout" style="background-color:Gray; height:100%;">
    <div id="myContent" style="background-color:Silver;">
      @RenderBody()    
    </div>
    <div id="myFooter" style="background-color:Silver;">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>

  @RenderScript()
</body>
```

Is there a way for me to do this? Or am I going to have to write every page individually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what i do, in each of your views create a section like this, put any html you want in it

**Any View:**

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Styles, more scripts, etc -->
}
```

Then back in your _Layout.cshtml you can render the section anywhere you want, the second parameter says if the page requires a Scripts section or not.

**_Layout.cshtml:** (anywhere you want)

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</head>
```